# Manual configuring network interfaces on Cubieboard

Tags: debian, networking, cubieboard, cubian

I have installed Cubian (It's Debian for the Cubieboard). After the system has started, the wired network works fine. I've read [this](https://github.com/cubieplayer/Cubian/wiki/Get-started-Cubian#connect-to-network) and configured the network interface(I added only the wlan0 settings):

```
//default
# the loopback interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

#
#auto eth0
allow-hotplug eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp

//my
auto wlan0
allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet dhcp
wireless-essid My_network_name
```

but when I try `sudo ifup wlan0` I get:

> No DHCPOFFERS received. No working leases in persistent database -
>   sleeping.

I have a MAC filter on my router, but I added the MAC address to the white list.

Also I can't understand why Cubian is connecting eth0, when there is

```
#auto eth0
```

in `/etc/network/interfaces`.

In the wiki I saw:

> If you absolutely don't need the wired network, please disable this
>   feature by comment or delete auto eth0.

It is commented out by default, why does eth0 start working after the system has started?

---

I have understood my bad. I have router and repeater with one ssid to cover a larger area, and Cubian doesn't know what to use. How can I fix it problem (maybe specify MAC address to connect) for feture?

Now it remembers where is dhcp and connect there fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because I have repeater, I need to tell Cubian where is DHCP thats why

```
auto wlan0
allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet dhcp
wireless-essid My_network_name
HWaddr DHCP_MAC_address
```

Answer (score 3):

What has worked for me in the past is using

```
wpa-ssid
```

rather than

```
wireless-essid
```

This will only work if you have `wpa_supplicant` installed.

As for your second question, my guess is, `eth0` connects automatically when you plug in a cable due to `allow-hotplug eth0`.

Comment: Thanks for idea, but `Invalid argument`; Also thanks for second question, and, I dont fully understand `allow-hotplug`. What it do and what is difference beetwen `auto` if it's also finds and connetcts automaticlally? P.S. sorry for my English:(

Comment: @McBodik What do you mean `Invalid argument`? Where do you get this error message? `hotplug` refers to the event generated when you plug in/out a peripheral to your system. The directive `allow-hotplug` allows the state of this interface to be changed by `hotplug` events. `auto eth0` just tells it to connect automatically at boot time.

Comment: When i try `sudo ifup wlan0`: 
`ioctl[SIOCSIWAP]: Operation not permitted
ioctl[SIOCSIWESSID]: Operation not permitted
ioctl[SIOCSIWENCODEEXT]: Invalid argument
ioctl[SIOCSIWENCODEEXT]: Invalid argument` after that is doing his "usual job"...

Comment: @McBodik Sorry, my bad. It should be `wpa-ssid` not `wpa-essid`. I corrected the answer.

Comment: The same:( Maybe it's because no wpa-psk?

Comment: @McBodik Try with an empty `wpa-psk` (i.e. `wpa-psk ""`)

Comment: No, there the same error. Also, I fogot to write that: `DHCPDISCOVER on wlan0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 4`. Interesting because my dhcp adress is 192.168.1.1.